# In automotive electronics ECUs, why is an external EPROM IC often used instead of the MCU's internal EPROM?

Tags: design, automotive

I am a bachelor of vehicle engineering.
It's easy to see many Automotive class MCU own interior EPROM,for example S9S08DZ,S9S12XS and some PIC 8-lead chips.
But,I have seem many Automotive electronics ECU use a EPROM IC(for example M95320).
Why they don't use MCU internal EPROM directly?
Is it because of lifetime?
I know some PICF12 8-lead watchdog MCU own interior EPROM,they won't lose power.(Beacuse they are watchdog MCU)

Answer (score 3):

I used to work in automotive, and there could be any number of reasons to speculate on. First and most obvious is size -- if the internal EEPROM (or other non-volatile media) isn't large enough, an external part is obviously needed.

Next is qualification. If a SW team has already written a driver for an EEPROM and HW has qualified that it meets AEC-Q100 and other internal tests, it might be "cheaper" to use the external device initially to meet schedule, and revise the design at a later date to optimize for cost.

Additionally, in the old days, the EEPROM was a socketed device that was programmed externally and then placed on the boards during assembly. Often you'll see aftermarket modifications that change the contents of that device; modern tuning companies just reflash the MCU itself, though.

Comment: Thx,it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of four reasons: one is component availability: if you design for a particular IC with integrated program memory, you basically need to use that (exact) MCU. But if the program is external, then you can use any available MCU, with or without program memory

Second reason is cost. External memory ICs are almost invariably cheaper than the same amount of memory integrated into the MCU. This cost difference comes from the semiconductor process differences or bonding+packaging+testing workflow complexity.

Third reason might be reliability; you might not want to put programmed ICs into a reflow oven. I'm not sure about this, but I would feel safer to program the IC externally with a gang programmer or order the ICs from the vendor already programmed, and then push them into sockets after production so that the programmed ICs are never heated up.

Fourth reason might be product differentiation. Perhaps the same ECU is used with different software in different models. Using an external IC for the program allows the manufacturer to make all units in a single lot and choose the software version at a very late stage in production.

Answer (score 1):

On very old ECUs, the micro-controller has a write-once ROM that can only be programmed at the factory. The Volkswagen Digijet ECU has an Intel MCS-48 P80A48H, using an Intel M2716 2K x 8 UV-Erasable EPROM.

I'm sure the combination of it being a small size (1K x 8) and not re-programmable made it worthwhile designing the ECU with external EPROM.